# How to I properly fill outside a curved shape in pycairo?

Tags: python, mask, fill, cairo, pycairo

I am trying to fill the image area outside of a custom curved shape in Pycairo, however am struggling to achieve this. I have managed to get the result I require by stroking the shape with a large thickness and drawing multiple shapes of increasing size on top of each other, however this solution is inefficient (I care about efficiency as I will be needing to draw 1200 shapes quickly, which currently takes 1 minute). I think there might be a way to use a mask or clip or something similar, but can't find anything online that helps. If there is a way to specify that the stroke is drawn only outside the path, not on both sides, that could also be a solution.

Anyone out there no of a better way to achieve this?
Here's the code I use to draw a curved shape, the calculate_curve_handles function just returns two curve handles between the two sides of the shape based on the curve_point_1 and 2 offsets. The polygon function returns the vertex locations for an N sided polygon

```
        vertices = polygon(num_sides, shape_radius + (scale * (line_thickness-20)), rotation, [x + offset[0], y + offset[1]])
            for i in range(len(vertices)):
                start_point = [vertices[i][0], vertices[i][1]]
                cr.move_to(start_point[0], start_point[1])

                if i == len(vertices)-1:
                    end_point = [vertices[0][0], vertices[0][1]]
                else:
                    end_point = [vertices[i+1][0], vertices[i+1][1]]
                point_1, point_2 = calculate_curve_handles(start_point, end_point, curve_point_1_offset, curve_point_2_offset)
                cr.curve_to(point_1[0], point_1[1], point_2[0], point_2[1], end_point[0], end_point[1])
        cr.set_line_cap(cairo.LINE_CAP_ROUND)
        cr.fill()
```

This is the desired result, achieved with many stroked objects layered on top of each other:

[image]

This is what I get when I try to use cr.fill() on the curved path:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I just figured out that if I move the `move_to()` function outside of the for loop for the vertices, it draws the shape properly.

Then by setting the fill rule to `cr.set_fill_rule(cairo.FILL_RULE_EVEN_ODD)` and drawing a large rectangle behind the shape, I can get the desired effect int even less time.

```
cr.move_to(vertices[0][0], vertices[0][1])
            for i in range(0, len(vertices)):
                start_point = [vertices[i][0], vertices[i][1]]

                if i == len(vertices)-1:
                    end_point = [vertices[0][0], vertices[0][1]]
                else:
                    end_point = [vertices[i+1][0], vertices[i+1][1]]
                point_1, point_2 = calculate_curve_handles(start_point, end_point, curve_point_1_offset, curve_point_2_offset)
                cr.curve_to(point_1[0], point_1[1], point_2[0], point_2[1], end_point[0], end_point[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for now. Basically for every side of the shape, I find a point that extends from the vector between the centre of the object and the vertex, well outside the drawing area. Then I fill each line segment as a separate shape

```
def calculate_bounds(start_point, end_point, centre_point):
    direction = np.subtract(start_point, centre_point)
    normalised_dir = direction / np.sqrt(np.sum(direction ** 2))
    bound_1 = start_point + normalised_dir * 5000

    direction = np.subtract(end_point, centre_point)
    normalised_dir = direction / np.sqrt(np.sum(direction ** 2))
    bound_2 = end_point + normalised_dir * 5000

    return bound_1, bound_2
```

Then the code for drawing the polygon is:

```
            for i in range(0, len(vertices)):
                start_point = [vertices[i][0], vertices[i][1]]
                cr.move_to(start_point[0], start_point[1])

                if i == len(vertices)-1:
                    end_point = [vertices[0][0], vertices[0][1]]
                else:
                    end_point = [vertices[i+1][0], vertices[i+1][1]]
                point_1, point_2 = calculate_curve_handles(start_point, end_point, curve_point_1_offset, curve_point_2_offset)
                cr.curve_to(point_1[0], point_1[1], point_2[0], point_2[1], end_point[0], end_point[1])
                bound_1, bound_2 = calculate_bounds(start_point, end_point, [x + offset[0], y + offset[1]])
                cr.line_to(bound_2[0], bound_2[1])
                cr.line_to(bound_1[0], bound_1[1])
                cr.fill_preserve()
                cr.stroke()
```